Create an ISO image from live SUSE server
I have SUSE server, over the years I have installed couple RPM package and 3rd party tools on the server. Now I'm trying to create ISO image on the live server using kiwi-ng  tools to include all installed package . but its failing with following error
[
 DEBUG   ]: 09:08:57 | EXEC: [rm -f /home/root/my-image/build/image-root/etc/sysconfig/proxy]
[ DEBUG   ]: 09:08:57 | Looking for cp in /usr/bin/habanatools:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
[ DEBUG   ]: 09:08:57 | EXEC: [cp /home/root/my-image/build/image-root/usr/share/fillup-templates/sysconfig.proxy /home/root/my-image/build/image-root/etc/sysconfig/proxy]
[ DEBUG   ]: 09:08:57 | Looking for rm in /usr/bin/habanatools:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
[ DEBUG   ]: 09:08:57 | EXEC: [rm -f /home/root/my-image/build/image-root/etc/resolv.conf.kiwi /home/root/my-image/build/image-root/etc/resolv.conf.sha /home/root/my-image/build/image-root/etc/hosts.kiwi /home/root/my-image/build/image-root/etc/hosts.sha /home/root/my-image/build/image-root/etc/sysconfig/proxy.kiwi /home/root/my-image/build/image-root/etc/sysconfig/proxy.sha]
[ ERROR   ]: 09:08:57 | KiwiInstallPhaseFailed: System package installation failed: No provider of 'suse-build-key' found.
No provider of 'PackageHub-release' found.
No provider of 'desktop-data-SLE' found.
No provider of 'gio-branding-SLE' found.
No provider of 'gpg-pubkey' found.
No provider of 'gtk2-branding-SLE' found.
No provider of 'gtk3-branding-SLE' found.
No provider of 'lib64readline8' found.
No provider of 'libicu73_2' found.
No provider of 'libicu73_2-ledata' found.
No provider of 'libprocps8' found.
No provider of 'lifecycle-data-sle-module-basesystem' found.
No provider of 'lifecycle-data-sle-module-python3' found.
No provider of 'lifecycle-data-sle-module-server-applications' found.
No provider of 'python310' found.
No provider of 'release-notes-sles' found.
No provider of 'sle-module-basesystem-release' found.
No provider of 'sle-module-desktop-applications-release' found.
No provider of 'sle-module-development-tools-release' found.
No provider of 'sle-module-legacy-release' found.
No provider of 'sle-module-python3-release' found.
No provider of 'sle-module-server-applications-release' found.
No provider of 'systemd-presets-branding-SLE' found.
No provider of 'wallpaper-branding-SLE' found.



How to fix it or ignore the packages with no provide ?
kiwi-ng --debug  system build --description kiwi-descriptions/suse/x86_64/suse-leap-15.5   --set-repo obs://openSUSE:Leap:15.5/standard --target-dir /home/${USER}/my-image
